# ember - need template to show records for nested route

Tags: ember.js

it seems that i am not setting up my model hook in my router correctly because my data is rendering in the template. but maybe there is something else that i'm missing

here is my router

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('movies', function() {
    this.route('show', { path: ':movie_id'}, function() {
      this.resource('rewrites', function() {
        this.route('show', { path: ':id'});
        this.route('new');
        this.route('edit');
      });
    });
    this.route('edit', { path: ':movie_id/edit'});
    this.route('new');
  });
});
```

in my index template for rewrites below, templates/rewrites/index.hbs, i need to show all the rewrites that are for one particular movie

```
{{outlet}}

{{link-to 'Add a New Rewrite' 'rewrites.new'}}

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Script</th>
      <th>Author</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each rewrite in movie}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{rewrite.name}}
        </td>
        <td>{{rewrite.script}}</td>
        <td>{{rewrite.author}}</td>
        <td>{{link-to 'Edit this Rewrite' 'rewrites.edit' this}}</td>
        <td><a href="#" {{action 'delete' rewrite}}>Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my model setup in my route, routes/rewrites/index.js, is

```
model: function() {
    var movie = this.modelFor('movies.show');
    return this.store.findAll('rewrite', { movie:movie });
  },
```

i've tried many things for the model, also tried

```
return this.store.findAll('rewrite');
```

either way the template is found and rendered, but there is no data
after creating rewrite 2, i've then tried

```
return this.store.find('rewrite', 2);
```

and that does not render any data either.

UPDATE: 
the router above is correct. the templates/rewrites/index.hbs above should be `{{#each rewrite in model}}`
and the model hook should be

```
 model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('movies.show').get('rewrites');
  },
```

also, this app's api is a rails app. and in the rails serializer for movie, i needed to add the has_many to sideload rewrites as in:

```
class MovieSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :director, :releaseDate, :cast, :description, :imageUrl
  has_many :rewrites, embed: :ids, include: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `each` is incorrect; `movie` is a single object, not an array to iterate over. Try this:

```
{{#each rewrite in movie.rewrites}}
```

At least, assuming your object model is such that a movie `hasMany` rewrites. If you really want to load the rewrites in the route independently, you can iterate over them like this:

```
{{#each rewrite in model}}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment. i have tried both. and it still is not rendering, which leads me to believe even more solidly that i am not setting up the model hook correctly.

Comment: Yeah, without seeing more code, it’s hard to say. Do you have the Ember Inspector addon installed? Then you could see if the model is properly loaded.